# Digit formatting in qwrap2

Tags: r

How do I control digit output in qwrap2 package? Thus far I have managed to make nice tables for rmarkdown output using the qwrap2 package.

Data set is *TheBIG_one2*  ;
5 Variables of interest : Dep., Anx., Pan., Neuro., & Neg.

```
summary_statistics = 
  list( 
    "Depression" = 
      list(
        "observations; mean+-(sd)" = ~qwraps2 ::mean_sd(TheBIG_one2$Depressed_Affect_T1, na_rm = TRUE),
        "min" = ~min(TheBIG_one2$Depressed_Affect_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "max" = ~max(TheBIG_one2$Depressed_Affect_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Kurtosis" = ~kurtosis(TheBIG_one2$Depressed_Affect_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Skew" = ~skewness(TheBIG_one2$Depressed_Affect_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Missing" = ~sum(is.na(TheBIG_one2$Depressed_Affect_T1))
      ),
    "Anxiety" = 
      list(
        "observations; mean+-(sd)" = ~qwraps2 ::mean_sd(TheBIG_one2$Anxiety_T1, na_rm = TRUE),
        "min" = ~min(TheBIG_one2$Anxiety_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "max" = ~max(TheBIG_one2$Anxiety_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Kurtosis" = ~kurtosis(TheBIG_one2$Anxiety_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Skew" = ~skewness(TheBIG_one2$Anxiety_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Missing" = ~sum(is.na(TheBIG_one2$Anxiety_T1))
  ),
    "Panic"  = 
    list(
      "observations; mean+-(sd)" = ~qwraps2 ::mean_sd(TheBIG_one2$Panic_T1, na_rm = TRUE),
        "min" = ~min(TheBIG_one2$Panic_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "max" = ~max(TheBIG_one2$Panic_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Kurtosis" = ~kurtosis(TheBIG_one2$Panic_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Skew" = ~skewness(TheBIG_one2$Panic_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Missing" = ~sum(is.na(TheBIG_one2$Panic_T1))
    ),
  "Neuroticism"  = 
    list(
      "observations; mean+-(sd)" = ~qwraps2 ::mean_sd(TheBIG_one2$Neuroticism_T1, na_rm = TRUE),
        "min" = ~min(TheBIG_one2$Neuroticism_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "max" = ~max(TheBIG_one2$Neuroticism_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Kurtosis" = ~kurtosis(TheBIG_one2$Neuroticism_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Skew" = ~skewness(TheBIG_one2$Neuroticism_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Missing" = ~sum(is.na(TheBIG_one2$Neuroticism_T1))
    ),
  "Negative Affect"  = 
    list(
      "observations; mean+-(sd)" = ~qwraps2 ::mean_sd(TheBIG_one2$Negative_Affect_T1, na_rm = TRUE),
        "min" = ~min(TheBIG_one2$Negative_Affect_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "max" = ~max(TheBIG_one2$Negative_Affect_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Kurtosis" = ~kurtosis(TheBIG_one2$Negative_Affect_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Skew" = ~skewness(TheBIG_one2$Negative_Affect_T1, na.rm = TRUE),
        "Missing" = ~sum(is.na(TheBIG_one2$Negative_Affect_T1))
  
      ))
```

I use this code to build table

```
Table1 = qwraps2::summary_table(TheBIG_one2, summary_statistics)
```

I have 3 tables for 3 times, so

```
Table_Output = cbind(Table1, Table2, Table3)


print(Table_Output,
      rtitle = "Internalizing Scores; No Log Transformations",
      cnames = c("Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 3"))
```

[image]

For the life of me I can not get my skew & kurtosis values to round to 3 digits. I am not sure where to put the arguments.

Comment: Is the `TheBIG_one2` something every educated person should know where to find and download????

Comment: @IRTFM , no. Just the dataset I use.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of my question. Please read [MCVE]. If you have difficulties with the mechanics of building and presenting a MCVE then you could do a search for the classic question "How to make a great reproducible example in R".